# OSGi - get ds service by name (id)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, osgi, declarative-services

I am newbie in OSGi. I have googled about a few hours but couldn't find the answer. Maybe my understanding is wrong. So the problem. Lets suppose I have a component.

```
<component name="sample.component" immediate="true">
  <implementation class="sample.SampleComparator" />
  <service>
    <provide interface="java.util.Comparator" />
  </service>
</component>
```

and in code:

```
ServiceReference[] serviceReferences = 
    bundleContext.getServiceReferences(
        java.util.Comparator.class.getName(), "(name=sample.component)");
```

But I get `null`. Where is the mistake? Is filter `(name=sample.component)` right? Or how can I set id of the service and lookup by it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of the service property is "component.name", not "name".

If you do this, it will work:

```
getServiceReferences(java.util.Comparator.class.getName(),"(component.name=sample.component)");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! If you know is this the only way to set id (name) of service? I mean we can use only component.name?

Comment: It is better to use service.pid as it is unique even if you create your component in the way that it is instantiated multiple times based on configuration (see configurationFactory=true). service.pid is a persistent id that is will be the same after restart. Filtering on service.pid should come also from a persistent configuration (see referenceName.target inside a component configuration)